# Looking for error codes defined for OneDrive consumer

Tags: onedrive

I am working on an application that is communicating with OneDrive through REST APIs (https://apis.live.net/v5.0), when the communication fails, OneDrive will return an error object, such as 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "resource_quota_exceeded", 
        "message": "The user has reached his or her storage quota limit."
    }
}
In order to map error back, I need to get all error codes defined at OneDrive, however, I can not find it online. Could you please provide the list of error codes defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the possible status codes that may be returned by the REST response.

In this case, you would get `507` with `The user doesn't have enough available storage.` description.

For Comprehensive list of status codes refer MSDN Dev center - [Returned status codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631844.aspx#Returned_status_codes).